# Why I can not make a file that partially match another in the same directory in Spacemacs?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I got into a situation in Spacemacs. Suppose, I have following files in my directory--

```
fileA.bak
fileB
fileA-new
fileC.bak
```

Here, If I want to create a file named `fileC` and do `SPC-f-f` it will suggest me `fileC.bak` in the mini-buffer. After that whatever I press `TAB` or `Enter` and any other key, it will open `fileC.bak`. Why can not I create a new file named `fileC`.

Comment: I am using `counsel-find-file` with `spacemacs`, I use `C-M-j` to create file to ignore suggestions.

Comment: I think that worked, Thank you!